# What's the best way to order a list by myself?

Tags: angular

I have a list of items and I'd like to sort this entries by myself.

For example the heroes list and I'd like to sort heroes in my favourite order.
What's the best way to do this?
At the moment I'm using a number array for sort. But it's not really ease of use. I have to set a number for each hero. If I have to change the positions of the items I have to change the numbers.

Is there a better way? 
It's possible to use drag and drop to order the entries. And how do I use this?

For (hero) Example here is a list of heroes:

```
[
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
]
```

And my favourites are:

1. Tornado
2. Celeritas
3. Dr IQ

And tomorrow is Narco my new favourite (number 1) and I like to reorder this array. This array is loading from a service without any order.

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to implement the actual sorting algorithm yourself, or do you want to define the sorting order, e.g. using some sort of comparator or sorting key function?

Comment: [`Array/sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) can take a custom sort function and sort any kind of data, not just numbers

Comment: @tobias_k hope it's now clearer.

Comment: Sort by whatever property you want and use index for display numbers

Comment: I like to move Dr IQ from 3. to 1. position. After that I like to add Dynama between 1. and 2. position. How can I solve this problem? Is there an easy way? I can store a new array with my favourite order. I think for small datasets is okay but not for big datasets.

Comment: Array.sort() is what you are looking for, but it's not really easy to use it at first. You are asking for a custom sort which is not logically related. So there is no way you can sort this programmatically without touching anything else.